# Fatal error: __autoload() is no longer supported, use spl_autoload_register() instead in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\marimar\includes\functions.php on line 37

Tags: php, database

I am trying to run some of my code by each time, I am getting this error, I am using the latest version of PHP.

I replaced my caused as per the error; from this

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
        $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
        $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
        if(file_exists($path)){
            require_once($path);
        }else{
            die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
        }
```

to this

```
function spl_autoload_register($class_name) {
        $class_name = strtolower($class_name);
        $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php";
        if(file_exists($path)){
            require_once($path);
        }else{
            die("The file {$class_name}.php could not be found.");
        }
```

then got another error message

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare spl_autoload_register() in D:\XAMPP\htdocs\marimar\includes\functions.php on line 37
```

Any help on how to solve this.
here is [the complete code](https://www.mediafire.com/file/l1hwccshou9dhjh/functions.php/file).

Answer (score 1):

try this.it worked for me

```
spl_autoload_register( function( $class_name )
{ 
    $class_name = strtolower( $class_name );
    $path = LIB_PATH.DS."{$class_name}.php"; 
    if( file_exists( $path ) ) 
        require_once($path); 
    else
        die( "The file {$class_name}.php could not be found." );
});
```